# Error: reference to non-static member function

Tags: c++, syntax

I keep getting a compiler error at 6 points in my code that claim that a "reference to non-static member function must be called" in my Executive.cpp file, I can't figure out what the issue is but I believe it might be some sort of syntax error either in my Executive class or my ShapeContainer class. The ShapeContainer class just holds an array of various shapes from a Shape Interface that includes circles, triangles, and rectangles. Everything is read in from a file and the goal is to store the shapes from the file into the ShapeContainer class and then print certain areas the file says to do so.

Part of my Executive class and where the errors are:

```
    //Executive.h
    //...
    class Executive
    {
    private:
        int m_size;
        int check;
        ShapeContainer Shapes(int size);
        ifstream inFile;
        string FileName;
    public:
      Executive(string FileName);
      void run();
    };
    //...

    //Executive.cpp
    //...          
      inFile.open(FileName);
        int number;
        inFile >> number;
      while(check != 1)
      {
        string command = "";
        int index = 0;
        string shape = "";
        double value1 = 0;
        double value2 = 0;
        inFile >> command >> index >> shape >> value1 >> value2;
        if(command == "ADD")
        {
          if(shape == "CIRC")
          {
            Circle myCirc(value1);
            try
            {
              Shapes.add(myCirc, index);//ERROR 1
            }
            catch(std::runtime_error& rte)
            {
              cout << rte.what() << "\n";
            }
          }
          else if(shape == "TRI")
          {
            Triangle myTri(value1, value2);
          try
          {
              Shapes.add(myTri(value1, value2), index);//ERROR 2
          }
            catch(std::runtime_error& rte)
            {
              cout << rte.what() << "\n";
            }
          }
          else if(shape == "REC")
          {
            Rectangle myRect(value1, value2);
            try
            {
              Shapes.add(myRect(value1, value2), index);//ERROR 3
            }
            catch(std::runtime_error& rte)
            {
              cout << rte.what() << "\n";
            }
          }
        }
        else if(command == "DELETE")
        {
          try
          {
            Shapes.remove(index);//ERROR 4
          }
          catch(std::runtime_error& rte)
          {
            cout << rte.what() << "\n";
          }
        }
        else if(command == "PRINT")
        {
          cout << "Shape at index " << index << ": ";
          try
          {
            cout << Shapes.shapeName(index) << " area = ";//ERROR 5
          }
          catch(std::runtime_error& rte)
          {
            cout << rte.what() << "\n";
          }
          try
          {
            cout << Shapes.area(index);//ERROR 6
          }
          catch(std::runtime_error& rte)
          {
            cout << rte.what() << "\n";
          }
        }
        else if(command == "EXIT")
        {
          cout << "Exiting...\n";
          check = 1;
        }
      }
      inFile.close();
    //...
```

Here is my ShapeContainer header file:

```
    //ShapeContainer.h
    #ifndef SHAPECONTAINER_H
    #define SHAPECONTAINER_H
    #include "Shape.h"
    #include <stdexcept>
    class ShapeContainer
    {
       public:
       ShapeContainer(int size); //initialize pointers in m_arrayOfShapes to nullptr
       ~ShapeContainer();
       double area(int index) const; //throws a std::runtime_error if index is invalid, meaning out of range OR index has nullptr
       std::string shapeName(int index) const; //throws a std::runtime_error if index is invalid, meaning out of range OR index has nullptr
       void add(Shape* shapePtr, int index); //throws a std::runtime_error if index is invalid OR if shapePtr is nullptr
       void remove(int index); //throws a std::runtime_error if the index is invalid OR there is no object to delete
       private:
       Shape** m_arrayOfShapes;
       int m_size;
    };
    #endif
```

And here is my Shape interface with an example of one of my shapes:

```
    //Shape.h
    #ifndef SHAPE_H
    #define SHAPE_H
    #include <string>
    class Shape
    {
       public:
       virtual double area() const = 0;
       virtual std::string shapeName() const = 0;
       virtual ~Shape() {}
    };
    #endif

    //Circle.h
    #ifndef CIRCLE_H
    #define CIRCLE_H
    #include "Shape.h"
    class Circle:public Shape
    {
        public:
        Circle(double radius);
        double area()const;
        std::string shapeName()const;
        private:
        double m_radius;
    };
    #endif

    //Circle.cpp
    #include "Circle.h"
    Circle::Circle(double radius)
    {
        m_radius = radius;
    }
    double Circle::area()const
    {
        return((m_radius * m_radius) * 3.14);
    }
    std::string Circle::shapeName()const
    {
        return("Circle");
    }
```

Here is the input file and my hopeful output:

```
    //file.txt
    5
    ADD 0 CIR 5.5
    ADD 1 TRI 2.5 6.6
    PRINT 0
    ADD 2 REC 10.5 20.25
    PRINT 99
    PRINT 2 
    EXIT

    //output
    Shape at index 0: Circle area = 95.0331
    Shape at index 99: Does not exist
    Shape at index 2: Rectangle area = 212.625
    Exiting...
```

Comment: That's too much code to go through to figure out where the problem is. Please create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: I've edited it with less code now.

Comment: Please show where variable `Shapes` is defined.

Comment: Just updated it, it's in the header file for the Executive class.

Comment: `Shapes.add(myCirc, index)`: Shape.add() is expecting a shape ptr, you pass a Circle object. Create first a pointer to a circle, and cast it to a shape pointer with dynamic_cast

Comment: How exactly do I go about doing that? I have very little knowledge of pointers.